# Handling large inputs in python

Tags: python, io

I started learning programming a few months ago and just recently found [codechef](http://codechef.com).
The problem is that on problems that use large amounts of input my code alwaqys exceehe time limit. I can't even seem to make the [input test](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST) work.

Description from codechef:

> Input
>
> The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=10^7). The next
>   n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than
>   10^9, each.

Output

> Write a single integer to output, denoting how many integers ti are
>   divisible by k.

Here's the code:

```
n, t = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
c = 0
for i in range(n):
    if not int(input()) % t:
        c += 1
print(c)
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. How can I handle this faster?

Comment: can you paste the input?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: You mean all 20MB? The problem is called "Enormous Input Test"

Comment: @agf Yes it is. The programs must read from standart input and write to standart output.

Comment: "Enormous Input Test" is not something where Python would be appropriate. Why not just use C or something for these simple programs and use Python for the other, more interesting problems where the actual idea of your algorithm is much more important than processing speed?

Comment: @NiklasB. What? You can process 20MB of data in Python in very little time.

Comment: @agf: Yes, but obviously the problem requires you to do it in even *less* time. Maybe it would be possible to use some Python magic to make this fast enough, but surely it's simpler to just do it in C. **EDIT:** It seems like this is one of the problems where you can't get fast enough without using `psyco`.

Comment: @NiklasB. Take a look at the accepted answer.

Comment: @agf: Nice. Doesn't change my opinion though. Note that I didn't say it wasn't *possible* to do it in Python, I just said that this is one of the problems where raw speed is more important than thinking, and in that case I'd go with the simpler solution of just hacking it in C (which doesn't really take any longer).

Comment: @g NiklasB. I would argue thinking is important here -- something like `sum(not int(line) % t for line in sys.stdin)` would probably be significantly faster. On Python 3, you could get Python 2 performance by using `sys.stdin.buffer` as well. The idea that "Python is slow" is often not true for all practical purposes.

Comment: @NiklasB. It's true that c would be mush faster  python:43.25s c:~5s I've seen some JAVA finish in less than 2s.

Comment: @agf: I am very aware of this fact. I usually choose the highest-level language for the job that can be bent to solve a task in an acceptable amount of time. However, I think the example you gave is less about algorithmic thinking then about knowing what is fast in Python and what is slow and adapting your code accordingly. But I guess we can come to the conclusion that this is quite doable in both languages: C and Python.

Comment: @agf see my answer. Not even using buffer is enough to help python 3, at least not in this test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should really be a comment, but anyway.

Note that there's an accepted Python 2 solution [here](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/989892), with runtime 45.77s, so it's clearly possible.  I think you're a victim of Python 3's slow I/O (looks like they're using 3.1.2). On a two million line input file (which happens not to have any numbers which are divisible): there's not much difference when there are a lot), on a version of your code modified to be compatible with 2 and 3, I get:

```
~/coding$ time python2.6 enormread.py < sample.txt 
0

real    0m3.971s
user    0m3.712s
sys 0m0.256s
~/coding$ time python2.7 enormread.py < sample.txt 
0

real    0m2.637s
user    0m2.428s
sys 0m0.204s
~/coding$ time python3.2 enormread.py < sample.txt 
0

real    0m10.412s
user    0m10.065s
sys 0m0.344s
~/coding$ time ~/sys/Python-3.3.0a2/python enormread.py < sample.txt 
0

real    0m6.776s
user    0m6.336s
sys 0m0.436s
~/coding$ time pypy enormread.py < sample.txt 
0

real    0m2.211s
user    0m1.948s
sys 0m0.028s
```

To throw @agf's `(sum(not int(line) % t for line in sys.stdin[.buffer]))` into the mix:

```
~/coding$ time python2.7 enormfast.py < sample.txt 
0

real    0m1.454s
user    0m1.436s
sys 0m0.016s
~/coding$ time python3.2 enormfast.py < sample.txt 
0

real    0m2.243s
user    0m2.228s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Comment: That was it. Mine and the other guys code is roughly the same, and when I run it with 2.5 it finishes in time.

Comment: Nice edit. Another +1 if I could. Glad to see I was right that how you write the code matters. I'm actually a little surprised to see that much of a difference between Python 2.7 and 3.2, but there are a lot of things going on, with I/O changes, generator expression changes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the test is impossible to run using python3 because of it's slower IO performance. Below is the fastest code that I could write. Looking back a few months in the results this seems to be the fastest python solution.
Using len() is about 3 times as fast as sum() that @agf recommended.

---

```
python2.5:  8.28s

import sys
import psyco
psyco.full()

def main():
    n, k = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
    print len([x for x in sys.stdin if not int(x) % k])

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Python, you could try speeding up your solutions by adding the following two lines to the start of your file:
>
> ```
> import psyco
> psyco.full()
> ```

http://www.codechef.com/wiki/faq#Why_do_I_get_a_Time_Limit_Exceeded

Comment: It doesn't make any difference in this case. It runs in roughly the same time with or without it. It appears that the bottleneck in this case is the slow IO of python 3 as it's working with 2.5